# PG_restore. What does it do?

Tags: postgresql

I read these docs:

> Description
>
> pg_restore is a utility for restoring a PostgreSQL database from an
>   archive created by pg_dump in one of the non-plain-text formats. It
>   will issue the commands necessary to reconstruct the database to the
>   state it was in at the time it was saved. The archive files also allow
>   pg_restore to be selective about what is restored, or even to reorder
>   the items prior to being restored. The archive files are designed to
>   be portable across architectures.
>
> pg_restore can operate in two modes. If a database name is specified,
>   pg_restore connects to that database and restores archive contents
>   directly into the database. Otherwise, a script containing the SQL
>   commands necessary to rebuild the database is created and written to a
>   file or standard output. This script output is equivalent to the plain
>   text output format of pg_dump. Some of the options controlling the
>   output are therefore analogous to pg_dump options.
>
> Obviously, pg_restore cannot restore information that is not present
>   in the archive file. For instance, if the archive was made using the
>   "dump data as INSERT commands" option, pg_restore will not be able to
>   load the data using COPY statements.

but it's still unclear to me if pg_restore just loads database data or if it also creates the structure of the database too.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the options you pass, and obviously in the stored information in the dump. If you keep reading through the documentation you will see this option:

> --data-only
>
> Restore only the data, not the schema (data definitions). Table data, large objects, and sequence values are restored, if
>   present in the archive.
>        This option is similar to, but for historical reasons not identical to, specifying --section=data.

That is obviously allowing you to restore only the schema but no the data.